# CEF browser is stuck loading forever

Tags: c++, browser, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm embedding a chromium browser into my C++ application (which is a plugin). To do this, I basically tore apart the CefClient example application that comes in CEF distributions, and tried to get it to work in my application.

Unfortunately, it's not getting all the way through the initialization process. I get the first 'load state changed' notificated from CEF, and then nothing after that. It sits there and spins. I should get a call from display_handler_on_address_change next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was pretty simple. The child processes weren't able to spawn, meaning that the initialization process would freeze before anything came on the screen.